# How do I extract a formula for distance from a metric that employs curvature?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, alternative-proof, general-relativity

Let's say I have a metric for spacetime that looks like this:
$$
ds^2 = -c^2dt^2+a^2(t)
       \left[\frac{dr^2}{1-kr^2}+r^2d\theta^2+r^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2\right]
$$
As I understand it, this is the Reduced Circumference version of the formula where we basically take the circumference as it's measured, but then reduce the radius such that $C=2\pi D$ where $D$ is the reduced radius.  In that way, basic trig operations can still return usable results.

I also know from basic trigonometry on a sphere that
$$D=\frac{\sin\left(r\sqrt{k}\right)}{\sqrt{k}}$$
when the curvature is positive.  Conceptually, this appears to be the same thing as the Reduced-circumference polar coordinates.  Is there a way to derive this relation from the metric?  If so, please show the steps.

I am basically trying to find the relation between $r$ and $\theta$ in a space with positive curvature, $k$ using my metric for that space.

Comment: What's curious is that if I integrate the spatial part of the metric, I get: $$ d\ell^2=\frac{dr^2}{1-kr^2} $$
$$ R = \int_0^r\,\frac{dr}{\sqrt{1-kr^2}} $$
$$ R = \frac{\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{k}\,r)}{\sqrt{k}} $$  Why do I get $sin^{-1}$ when I integrate, but $sin$ when I use trig?

Comment: Oops. $r$ is fixed and you want to integrate $d\phi$. Ultimately you need to use the $dr$ integral to relate the actual radius to $r$.

Comment: @TedShifrin - I am currently sifting through 10 different papers on Baryonic Acoustic Oscillations and if I clear out some room in my head to do this problem, I know I'm going to lose something else that's important.  Any chance you could lay out the steps that get me to the result I got doing the trigonometry?  It'd be very helpful and a great illustration of the power of the metric.

Comment: The metric on a sphere of radius $R$ is $R^2(d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta\,d\phi^2)$. Your curvature appears with $R=1/\sqrt{k}$. Take a geodesic circle of radius $\rho$ centered at the north pole. Then $R\theta = \rho$ and the circumference is $\int_0^{2\pi} R\sin\theta\,d\phi = 2\pi R\sin\theta = 2\pi\sin(\rho\sqrt K)/\sqrt K$.

Comment: @TedShifrin - Yes, I agree that the metric on the sphere is $R^2(d\theta^2+sin^2\theta d\phi^2)$.  I'm trying to get this to work with the established spacetime metric where the Reduced Circumference coordinates give the spatial metric as $$
dl^2 = \left[\frac{dr^2}{1-kr^2}+r^2d\theta^2+r^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2\right]$$Can you get from there to a formula of $$D=\frac{\sin\left(r\sqrt{k}\right)}{\sqrt{k}}$$If you can, post it as an answer and I'll up-vote it.  I'm sure it would be helpful to others if you can.

Comment: The point is that the $\rho$ in my formula will *now* be determined not by $R\theta = \rho$, but instead by $\int_0^R dr/\sqrt{1-kr^2} = \rho$. (By the way, it's too confusing using $r$ as both a parameter and as a variable determining the metric. That's why I switched to $\rho$.)

Comment: When I integrate $\frac{dr^2}{1-kr^2}$ over R, I get $$\rho=\frac{sin^{-1}\left(R\sqrt{k}\right)}{\sqrt{k}}$$  If I sub that into the radial formula, I get a mess that looks like:$$\frac{2\pi R sin\left(\frac{sin^-1\left(R\sqrt{k}\right)}{R\sqrt{k}}\right)}{\sqrt{k}}$$This doesn't simplify.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should coefficient  $a^2(t) $ be there in the metric ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First part*

It is customary to use capital letter $K$ to denote Gaussian curvature ( not $k$).  For positive Gauss curvature let $ K= 1/a^2$

I am supposing that you are trying to find a relation between $D$ and $r$.

On the question how to exploit the metric in order to find shrunk or reduced circumferential distance $r$ from arc distance  $D$ of 2D spherical surface.

For a given latitude or longitude ( same $(\phi, \theta)$ so $ d\phi=0, d\theta=0) $ these two terms vanish so we do not consider parallel circle, operate on cylindrical mode to obtain formula for ***geodesic distance $D$ between a pole and a geodesic parallel***:

$$ dD^2= \dfrac{dr^2}{1-Kr^2}=\dfrac{dr^2}{1-r^2/a^2} \; (r< a) $$

$$dD =\dfrac{dr}{\sqrt{1-r^2/a^2}} $$

$$ D =\int \dfrac{dr}{\sqrt{1-r^2/a^2}}= a \sin^{-1}\dfrac{r}{a}$$

so that the direct Reduced Circumferentially determined radius

$$ r = a \sin \dfrac{D}{a} = a \sin D \sqrt K \;  (r<a) \tag1 $$

[image]

From trigonometry of a sphere we have

$$ \dfrac{r}{a} =\sin \dfrac{D}{a}= \sin \phi_{co-latitude}\quad r<a \tag2 $$

***but not***

$$ \dfrac{D}{a} =\sin \dfrac{r}{a} \tag3$$
which as an error source in your simple trigonometric calculation  is clear.. as $ r$ cannot be greater then $D$.

Also reduced circumference is

$$ 2 \pi r < 2 \pi D $$

*Second part*

You are in other words looking at *geodesic polar coordinates* for the general case with North pole as center for these coordinates. Relation between $D$ and $\theta$ in general involves metric. Even if $D$ is an uncomfortable symbol,lengths are according to the metric:

$$ ds^2= dD^2+G_{D,\theta} \;d\theta^2 $$

involving first fundamental form coefficient $G_{D,\theta} $.

[image: Geodesic polar parameters]

It should be noted for generality that for $K<0$ circumferential dimension *increases* in hyperbolic geometry.